# Passport.js and Mongoose.js populate User on login - loses populated field on req.user

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

Using Mongoose.js, my authenticate method populates the field "companyRoles._company," but the populated data reverts to the company reference ID when I try to access the same populated field in my req.user object.

```
//Authentication 
UserSchema.static('authenticate', function(email, password, callback) {
  this.findOne({ email: email })
  .populate('companyRoles._company', ['name', '_id'])
    .run(function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return callback(err); }
      if (!user) { return callback(null, false); }
      user.verifyPassword(password, function(err, passwordCorrect) {
        if (err) { return callback(err); }
        if (!passwordCorrect) { return callback(null, false); }
        return callback(null, user);
      });
    });
});

//login post
app.post('/passportlogin', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err) }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/passportlogin') }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      console.log('req User');
      console.log(req.user); 
      return res.redirect('/companies/' + user.companyRoles[0]._company._id);
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});

app.get('/companies/:cid', function(req, res){
    console.log('req.user in companies:cid');
    console.log(req.user);   
});
```

After req.logIn, logging req.user shows
- companyRoles{_company: [Object]}

But when I redirect to /companies/:id route after logging in, it is showing the id and not a populated [object]
- companyRoles{_company: 4fbe8b2513e90be8280001a5}

Any ideas as to why the field does not remain populated?  Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem was that I was not populating the field in the passport.deserializeUser function, here is the updated function:

```
//deserialize
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id)
    .populate('companyRoles._company', ['name', '_id'])
    .run(function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
     });
});
```

Comment: For me, it worked with .exec(function (err, user) ... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your `res.redirect` you're trying to construct a URL by concatenating an object to a string. I doubt that will have the result you want. What do you expect the URL to look like?

Comment: Thanks ebohlman, you are correct. I didn't update the redirect url from when I was previously not populating the _company object.  I updated the code to now have _company._id.

Comment: Although, the problem still remains. In /companies/{companyId}, req.user.companyRoles[i]._company is an ObjectID and not a populated _company object (name, id, etc).  It's strange since req.user is a populated object when logging it in the req.logIn callback.

Comment: I think you need to show the code that handles `/companies/:companyId`. Remember that after the redirect, the browser is going to be making a completely new request and none of the properties you set on your original `req` object will automatically be present on the new one.

Comment: Just as a test to see what the req.user object is, I'm only logging the req.user object. (See above) The req.user object is fine except for the companyRoles[i]._company.  I thought the req.logIn function sets the session so that req.user does persist even after the redirect. Shouldn't this be the case?

Comment: The problem was that I needed to populate the same field in the passport deserializeUser function.  See edit above. Thanks @ebohlman